# JOptionPane running FileChooser

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Hello I'm working on a program with Java Swing and I have 4 option panes set up to get certain inputs, but when I run the program it'll show the option window, but as I close out of the option pane it goes and runs the last button I have to execute the rest of the program. I'm currently confused as to why. Here is the code for the actionPerformed() method and the method with the file chooser. Note the Option Panes are for getting inputs from radio buttons aside from a yes or no choice so the 4 check* methods are for looking at what radio button was pressed and what to do with that information.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("settings")) {
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, encryptPanel,
                "Settings Choices", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);

    }
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("paths")) {
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, pathsPanel,
                "Paths Options", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);

    }
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("tools")) {
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, toolsPane,
                "Tools Options", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);

    }
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("techniques")) {
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, methodPane,
                "Choose your encryption method", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
    }
    checkEncrypt(e.getActionCommand());
    checkPaths(e.getActionCommand());
    checkTools(e.getActionCommand());
    checkTech(e.getActionCommand());

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("go")) ;
    {
       runLauncher();

    }
}
private void runLauncher()
{

    directory.makeDir("PEP");
    JFileChooser getFile = new JFileChooser();
    getFile.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    int result = getFile.showOpenDialog(this);
    String str;
    int numWheels = Integer.getInteger(wheels.getText());
    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        str = getFile.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();


        int result2 = getFile.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (result2 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            String endFilePath = getFile.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            if(gOn)
            {
                launcher go = new launcher(str, endFilePath, numWheels, 5);
                go.run();
            }
            else
            {
                launcher go = new launcher(str, endFilePath, numWheels, selection);
                go.run();
            }
        }

        selection = 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from your question you have a couple of things going. Common practice is to start with capitals class names and then capitalize every first letter of every word. i.e. SomeVeryLongClassName. Second, if you call the same method over and over you are doing it wrong. Call it once and assign it to a variable. Example: String cmd = e.getActionCommand(); then you can use cmd instead. Third, only one command gets executed, that being said. Rather than using if if if ... etc. You should be using if else if else if  ... etc. Right now it does not make a difference but soon it will.

Comment: I appreciate the mistakes I need to fix. Still have to fix my other problem of it running that last end bit with every JOptionPane

Answer (score 3):

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("settings")) {
    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, encryptPanel,
            "Settings Choices", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
}

...

checkEncrypt(e.getActionCommand());
```

The `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(...)` method does not change the value of the `actionCommand`. It simply returns an int value representing which button was clicked.

So basically you are displaying the option pane for no reason because your code never uses the value returned from the option pane.

So maybe your code should be something like:

```
int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(...);
```

Then you do your processing based on the value returned.

```
checkEncrypt( option );
```

Or maybe the code should be something like:

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("settings")) 
{
    int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(...):
    checkEncrypt( option );
}
```

I don't know why you invoke those four methods separately.

In any case your code needs to be restructured.

Comment: I might not have explained that the JOptionPanes also have other buttons aside from the yes, no, cancel options.They are merely for popups to get other output from radio buttons. I don't know if the return value of JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(...) would give me the selected radio button and checkEncrypt(...) was a way to use shorten the actionListener method so I don't have that a page long and it checks to see what button the user selected.

Comment: @Snipeshot101, The point is you are not using any information from the JOptionPane. You just display the option pane and then ignore it. Maybe you should be using a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...)` to get input from the user. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and examples.

Comment: Ahh okay thank you for telling me a better way to go about doing that.

Comment: Still umm With that I get a textfield I don't need really except in maybe 1 of the panes I was looking at the other options on there maybe Message Dialog might help since I only need an ok button to exit out of the pane anyway

Comment: Still has the issue of opening the file chooser after the option pane closes

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you are doing. We don't know what you "toolsPane" or "methodPane" is. If you are just displaying a panel, then why don't you use the properties from that panel. The structure of you displayed code doesn't make sense but I don't have the whole picture so I can't advise anymore. You need to debug your logic. The code executes based on the values in your variables. If the actionCommand contains "go" then you start the launcher after all the option panes.